# Data loss while inserting data to BigQuery using Apache beam BigQueryIO

Tags: google-bigquery, apache-beam

I am using below code to insert data to BQ using apache Beam BigQueryIO. I read data from kafka(Beam KafkaIO) and process it and create Pcollection of String and then stream it to BQ. While writing data to BQ it is not writing all records to Table. It doesn't throw any exception also.

```
public class ConvertToTableRow extends DoFn<String, TableRow> {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private StatsDClient statsdClient;
private String statsDHost;
private int statsDPort = 9125;

public ConvertToTableRow(String statsDHost) {
    this.statsDHost = statsDHost;
}

@Setup
public void startup() {
    this.statsdClient = new NonBlockingStatsDClient("Metric", statsDHost, statsDPort);
}

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(@Element String record, ProcessContext context) {
    try {
        statsdClient.incrementCounter("bq.message");
        TableRow row = new TableRow();
        row.set("name", "Value");
        Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        DateFormat dateFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        Date date = new Date(timestamp);
        String insertDate = dateFormater.format(date);
        row.set("insert_date", insertDate);
        context.output(row);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        statsdClient.incrementCounter("exception.bq.message");
    }
}

@Teardown
public void teardown() {
    this.statsdClient.close();
}
```

}

```
private void streamWriteOutputToBQ(PCollection<TableRow> bqTableRows) {
    String tableSchema = //tableSchema;
    bqTableRows
    .apply((BigQueryIO.writeTableRows().skipInvalidRows().withMethod(Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
            .to("myTable").withJsonSchema(tableSchema)
            .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)));
        

}
```

I am not sure, if i am missing any configuration for BigQueryIO

Comment: Can you spot from which stage to which you are losing elements? You should be able to see the element count in the UI. Are you using windows? If so, may there be late data that gets discarded?

Comment: statsdClient.incrementCounter("bq.message") --> this metric count is coming proper and also there is no count for exception metric counter. So i assumed all message is reaching to this parDo. But some how all message is not getting inserted to BQ

Comment: If this counter is zero, can you try removing the try/catch block (or re-raising the exception after incrementing the counter) and ensure your pipeline still runs? If not, that should indicate (more loudly) what the issue is.

Comment: Actually i have already added log in exception block I had omitted this log while asking this question. LOGGER.error("Exception occured while preparing tableRow: {}, {}", record, e);